Repeat a number in a sequence n times and increment in R
How can I repeat a sequence every 4 times, but increase the base value by 1.
e.g. I want to repeat the number 2000, a total of 4 times which would be:
2000
2000
2000
2000

Then I would like the next values in the sequence to be:
2001
2001
2001
2001 

So the values in the sequence are repeated 4 times, but on the 5th time the value is incremented by 1 and repeated a further 4 times.
I would like to repeat this a for a total of say 10 times.
I have tried the seq() function in R but still stuck on how to increment the value.

Something like rep(seq(2000, length.out=10), each=4)

Depends on th output format, please specify. lapply(seq(10), \(i) rep(1999, 4)  + i)? Might be fast enough, but has overhead. rep() and a split-method will work too.

what happens If i have an odd length is the value recycled?

rep(2000:2009, each = 4)?

You could do this:
> m <- 10
> n <- 4
> as.vector(t(matrix(2000, m, n) + c(0, seq_len(m - 1))))
 [1] 2000 2000 2000 2000 2001 2001 2001 2001 2002 2002 2002 2002
[13] 2003 2003 2003 2003 2004 2004 2004 2004 2005 2005 2005 2005
[25] 2006 2006 2006 2006 2007 2007 2007 2007 2008 2008 2008 2008
[37] 2009 2009 2009 2009


You can use rep for this, leveraging the each argument:
> rep(2000:2002, each = 4)
 [1] 2000 2000 2000 2000 2001 2001 2001 2001 2002 2002 2002 2002

And can obviously add complexity to the vector you want to repeat on the front end based on your needs.
